# How to resolve IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working through a machine learning project in Visual Studio Code using Jupyter notebooks and Python 3.11.6. This is the line of code I have and the error I am receiving. The file I am working with has 84 rows × 759 columns so I am not sure why I am running into this issue.

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0,5:]) for df in dfs] 

dfs[0]



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 1
----> 1 dfs = [pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0,5:]) for df in dfs] 
      3 dfs[0]

Cell In[25], line 1, in (.0)
----> 1 dfs = [pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0,5:]) for df in dfs] 
      3 dfs[0]

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1147, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   1145     if self._is_scalar_access(key):
   1146         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
-> 1147     return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1148 else:
   1149     # we by definition only have the 0th axis
   1150     axis = self.axis or 0

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1652, in _iLocIndexer._getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1651 def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: tuple):
-> 1652     tup = self._validate_tuple_indexer(tup)
   1653     with suppress(IndexingError):
   1654         return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:940, in _LocationIndexer._validate_tuple_indexer(self, key)
...
   1645 len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
   1646 if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 1647     raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I have tried changing the index with different numbers but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that I can replicate this error by:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.iloc[0, 5:]
```

If any of your dataframes is empty, this will happen.

You could do something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

dfs = [pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3]}), 
       pd.DataFrame({"B": [1, 2, 3]}), 
       pd.DataFrame()]

dfs = [df for df in dfs if not df.empty]
```

Please note that based on your variable names, instantiating a df as pf.DataFrame(df) might be redundant

Comment: Thank you so much! It ended up being a limitation of Visual Studio code. I navigate to the cell above and clicked on excute cell and below and that did the trick :)